# Text-overflowing from input

Tags: html, css, input

[image]

The problem I am having is I am trying to stop the text overflowing from the right, I have tried setting padding-right to try and address the issue but still no luck. How can I go around this?

Here is my html, css file.

.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/testing.css" type="text/css" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <style type="text/css">
            /* Importing Nomralized CSS */
            @import url('css/normalize/normalize.css');

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="content-main-top" id="dpb">
                <p class="para">
                    Our new website is currently under<br/> development. It won't take long, please
                </p>
                <span id="clr" class="size" style="margin-top: 60px;"><h1 style="margin-top: 4px; margin-bottom: 3px;">sit tight!</h1></span>
                <p class="para" style="margin-bottom: 10px; color: #808285; margin-top: 30px; font-weight:">
                    Fill in your email address and we<br/>
                    will let you know when we launch.
                </p>
                <input type="email" class="bubble_email"><input type="submit" name="sub" value="Notify me!" class="button">
            </div>
            <div class="chairs" id="dpb"></div>
            <!-- end of container -->
        </div>
        <!-- Begin Footer -->
        <div id="footer">
            <!-- Start Container -->
            <div id="container">
                <!-- Footer Content -->
                <div class="content-main-bottom">
                    <p id="clear_footer">
                        <span style="color: #808285; font-weight: bolder; line-height: 30px; font-size: 17px;">Get in touch</span><br/>
                    <!-- Tweet Pic -->
                    <a href="https://www.twitter.com/TitanHealthcare" target="_blank" class="tweet"></a>
                        <span class="para">Phone: </span><span style="color: #808285; font-weight: bolder">0845 130 8022</span><br/>
                        <a href="mailto:info@titanhealthcare.co.uk">info@titanhealthcare.co.uk</a>
                    </p>
                    <p style="font-weight: lighter; font-size: 13px; color: #939598">
                        &copy; Titan Healthcare Limited 2014. All rights reserved.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <!-- End of content for footer -->
            </div>
            <!-- End of Container -->
        </div>
        <!-- End of footer -->
    </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.para {
    color: #7c7b7b;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 6px;
}

.para_b {
    color: #808285;
}
/*Misc ID'S */
#clr {
    color: #34a4b5;
}

/*Size class*/
.size {
    font-size: 43px;

}

.button {
    background-color:transparent;
    outline: none;
    border: 0px solid;
    margin-left: 1px;
    color: #34a4b5;
    font-weight: bold;

}


a:link {
    color: #34a4b5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#dpb {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

#clear_footer {
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 30px;

}

#container {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#footer {
    background-image: url('img/bottom_bar.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    clear: both;

}

.content-main-bottom {
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}

/* Images .classes */

.header {
    background-image: url('img/titan_header.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-top: 40px;
    /*Size properties */
    width: 980px;
    height: 143px;
}

.bubble_email {
    background-image: url('img/speech_bubble.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*Size properties*/
    width: 244px;
    height: 49px;

    /*Misc Prop*/
    background-repeat: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding: 0 6px;


}

.chairs {
    background-image: url('img/titan_chairs.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*Size properties*/
    width: 559px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.tweet {
    background-image: url('img/tweet_button.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*Size properties*/
    width: 368px;
    height: 72px;
    float: right;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Create Fiddle for it... There is no problem, It's working for me Chrome 32..

Comment: Still not working. It just keeps coming off the image.

Comment: Use a *fixed* `width` input box

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the issue here is that you need to understand that when you add *padding-right:20;* and the width is set to 244px then your input field then becomes 264px wide with a right padding of 20px, not 244px with a right padding of 20px as you would assume. So, to fix your issue you need to add a right padding of e.g. 10px and make the width of your input 234px.

Basically as long as your input width + padding-left + padding-right is equal to the width of your background image you will get the desired effect.

Solution (assuming your image is 250px wide):

```
.bubble_email {
    background-image: url('img/speech_bubble.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;            
    height: 49px;
    background-repeat: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin-top: 6px;

    width: 238px;
    padding: 0 6px;
}
```

Note the width being 238 + a padding of 6 on the left and 6 on the right = 250px.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .bubble_email
        {
            background-image: url('img/speech_bubble.jpg');
            background-repeat: no-repeat; /*Size properties*/
            width: 244px;
            height: 49px; /*Misc Prop*/
            background-repeat: none;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            padding-top: 0px;
            margin-top: 6px;
            padding: 0 6px;
        }
```

You just **decrease** the **width** to 240 or less in `.bubble_email`

OR

Add `padding-right: 15px;` or more in `.bubble_email`

OR

Stretch the background image like,

```
background-size:260px 50px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

Comment: You need to decrease the width, not increase! as adding padding inherently increases the width - thus you need to subtract horizontal padding from the width of the input to keep it the same size as the image.

Answer (score 0):

Put the sppech bubble image in one class, like so:

```
.speechBubbleImage {
background-image: url('img/speech_bubble.jpg');
}
```

Then put the rest in another class, and change the width, like so:

```
 .innerSpeechBubble
    {
        background-repeat: no-repeat; /*Size properties*/
        width: 200px; /* This is what you change */ 
        height: 49px; /*Misc Prop*/

        background-repeat: none;  /* This is redundant and I recommend don't use this */

        border: none;
        outline: none;
        padding-top: 0px;
        margin-top: 6px;
        padding: 0 6px;
    }
```

Without the img/speech_bubble.img image, its hard to tell you what width to put.

Now use this in HTML, like so

```
<div class='.speechBubbleImage">
<input type="email" class="innerSpeechBubble">
</div>

<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Notify me!" class="button">
```

This should work. Let me know what you get. And give the image if possible, so that i can put the exact width.

Comment: The issue is simply that he (or she) has subtracted 6px from the width of the input accounting for the padding (padding:0 6px;) but actually needs to subtract 12px - 6px for the left and 6px for the right. So the width should be 238px, not 244px. No need to separate classes, it's just a simple miscalculation :)

Answer (score -1):

Try to Use overflow hidden that may solve this problem.